# What can be achieved in Enterprise Corda is not achievable in Community version of CORDA

Tags: corda

We are working with a client who is interested in developing a application using Corda Ledger. While in the initial phase of development to first rollout in to Production, client is looking to see the capabilities of Corda Ledger using its community version. Subsequent to first Production rollout when the capabilities of Corda are on the display with its own client, they want to look beyond making this solution a enterprise solution using by procuring Corda enterprise license.

I am not getting much help in forming a delineating line of difference between Community and Enterprise version of Corda.

**What are essential features which cannot be built using community version ?

**who governs Community version ?

**Is there any support provided for Community version ?

**Can we create a distributed architecture using Community version (Corda nodes located on different physical servers) ?

**Can we create Corda network using Docker containers using Community version ?

**Is there any detailed document to draw the lines between community and enterprise version ?
 **

I have worked on community version of Corda using it for developing PoC, Where all nodes are located on same server and were not truly distributed**strong text**

Answer (score 2):

Corda Open Source and Enterprise are functionally identical. What Enterprise offers extra is the non-functional stuff that is required for mission-critical enterprise applications, which includes performance, HA, HSM integration, Enterprise Database integration, 24 X 7 Support, etc.

The community version id developed primarily by R3, while we also accept and encourage community contribution to the Corda Open Source project.

There is no Official R3 Production Support for Open Source Corda, however, you could ask questions and ask for solutions to your problems on our public slack channel (stack.corda.net) and also here on StackOverflow.

You can operate a network of OS Corda with nodes on different servers without any problems.